# XeTeX and Fedora: can't use OTF fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

When trying to compile a document with XeLaTeX, I'm getting the following error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Linux Libertine Slanted O" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

Now, I've got the font files installed, `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertineotf` contains the font files that I need.

Fontconfig doesn't see those files, however. I tried adding the directory with `fc-cache` and it reports having added 30 new fonts, but I still can't see them when running `fc-list`.

Now it all kinda works well on Linux Mint, I'm on Fedora now, and it somehow doesn't work anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Fedora 18, with everything latex related installed from the official repos.
`This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999 (TeX Live 2013/dev)` is what xelatex reports. Fontconfig is the one installed that came with Fedora 18.

Comment: you should tell us which version of fedora you're (now) using.  the banner that xetex produces when you start could help, too.  things may be different if you're using a “too old” version of xetex, or of fontconfig.

Comment: @wasteofspace ok, I added the information you asked me to provide.

Answer (score 1):

In section 4.2 (p6) of the `fontspec` manual, it says:

> **4.6 By file name**
>
> XETEX and LuaTEX also allow fonts to be loaded by file name instead of
>   font name. When you have a very large collection of fonts, you will
>   sometimes not wish to have them all installed in your system’s font
>   directories. In this case, it is more convenient to load them from a
>   different location on your disk. This technique is also necessary in XETEX when loading OpenType fonts that are present within your TEX
>   distribution, such as /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/ public. Fonts in
>   such locations are visible to XETEX but cannot be loaded by font
>   name, only file name; LuaTEX does not have this restriction.

This means that you cannot simply use

```
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
```

with XeLaTeX unless the file is seen by your system.

In order to use TeX distribution fonts with XeLaTeX, you need to load them by hand which gets very tedious.

Your best alternative is to use the `libertine` TeX package (`\usepackage{libertine}`).

Comment: it //is// the libertineotf package! I have installed this package, and you can even tell by the directory, it is installed. But still, fontconfig doesn't see it. It worked that way on Linux Mint, though

Comment: fontconfig would not see it and the `libertineotf` package would not be using it either. When you say that it is the `libertineotf` package, what do you mean? are you actually loading it in your tex file is `\usepackage{libertineoft}`. At the point an MWE would be highly advantageous as we abviously do not have all the information.

Comment: Ahh, I was a bit confused here: The distro has a package called <code>libterineotf</code>, I didn't try the latex package yet.

Comment: The most recent `libertine` package also provides OpenType support. If you have that package (5.3.0 is the latest version) you should use the `libertine` package, not `libertineotf` (but `libertineotf` will tell you that as well).

Comment: @Silex I must admit I am losing track with these:-) it used to be `libertine`, then they split it into `libertine` and `libertineotf`, and now you are telling me they have merged again?? Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @ArTourter: That's about right, but 'they' refers to different persons. The current maintainer actually has an account here.

Comment: Why not simply install the fonts on the system? Won't harm at all...

Comment: @Joseph The problem with this is that it is not a really portable solution. If like me you work of different computers with different OS (but with TeXlive on them) or if you collaborate on documents with other people, insisting that things are installed system wide may not be practical. It is however a solution and one that I did not exclude, I simply stated that for me the easiest solution was to load the `libertine` package, which sorts every thing out for you.

Comment: @ArTourter Then just specifying the directory where xelatex should find the fonts "just works".

Comment: @Joseph Well, the problem I've run into is actually caused by system wide fonts. See, on Linux Mint, the "special" fonts, things like slanted, outlines and shadows, are extra fonts. The official Libertine fonts, don't have extra fonts for that and Fedora doesn't provide them as well. I can work-around those problems mostly, but it's a huge inconvenience to say the least!

Comment: Installing  fonts = an inconvenience? No logic there.